# What's the regular expression for combining both "(.*?)" and "(.*?(\n))+.*?"?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

So, I'm building a simple compiler for HTML in javascript. I'm using the match() expression to match strings and tags. In trying to verify the expression:

```
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

I'm using:

```
var = str.match(/<p>(.*?)Paragraph/g);
```

However, it doesn't recognize the code, if in the html field, I type:

```
 <p>
 Paragraph</p>
```

So, I searched and found that if I use the following, it fixes the issue with the next line:

```
var = str.match(/<p>(.*?(\n))+.*?Paragraph/g);
```

But then if I revert to my first html code the problem persists. Is there a way that both of these situations can be handled? (while using the match function of course)

So it doesn't make a difference whether I type 
`<p>Paragraph</p>`
 or

```
<p>
 Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: parsing html with regexes is generally a bad idea. What if your input is like `<p>foo</p><p>Paragraph</p>`?

Answer (score 3):

In this part

```
(.*?(\n))+
```

change `+` to `*`. `+` means "any number of newlines 1 or more times". You want "0 or more times".

So fixed expression:

```
/<p>(.*?(\n))*.*?Paragraph/g
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't fill understand the expression and couldn't find any guide either. If you know any place where I can find the explanation, that'd be great.

Comment: Start with this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions Also check regexp breakdown: https://regex101.com/r/6xs9DT/1

Comment: and this all grouping is almost equal to `[\s\S]*?` @Daniyal